# How to refresh BabylonJs canvas?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

How can I refresh the scene or canvas after I changed canvas size in BabylonJs?
all I want is to re render the scene because the aspect ratio changes when the browser size is changed by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using `engine.resize()` method. See: https://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/3.1/engine#resize-rarr-void